# Facebook LoginButton is not logging out of session

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a logout button in one of my fragments and I attempt to logout when pressing it and then start a new activity. However the session is never ended. I know this because when I launch the next activity it has a button that says logout as opposed to the login text you normally see.

```
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                logout(user);
            }
        });

    }

    private void logout(GraphUser user){
         Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
         if(session != null && session.isOpened() && user != null){
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Do nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
         else {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Loggin out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
             session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
             startActivity(intent);

         }
        }

}
```

When I comment out the `logout(user)` call the app logs out sucessfully however then I don't start the new activity. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually logging the user out. After you make the check `if(session != null && session.isOpened() && user != null)` you don't actually do anything to log the user out. That is where you should call the facebook logout method.

Comment: The problem is that this is called even when the logout button is not pressed. So it would switch activities even when I don't want to

Comment: Then don't call the logout method if you don't actually want to log out. If I remember correctly, the Facebook SDK for Android will automatically track if the user is logged in or not and will change the button from login to logout functionality accordingly. Possibly in the activity that would appear after the logout make a check in the onResume method to see if the user is logged in. From there start the new activity as you were trying to do.